# How to display more than 64 / all warnings in MySQL (workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using **MySQL Workbench** to load a bigger `txt` file into my database. There are more than 200k rows and I'm aware that my last column causes a warning that I can ignore. However, I don't know if there are other warnings as well that I should be aware of, since this warning from the last column is displayed more than 64 times (it stops after 64).
[image]

My question now:

- Is there either a way to specify which columns can be ignored (in terms of warnings)
- Or that I can output more than 64 warnings?

I already checked in the logfile, if I can find more warnings but it stops there as well after 64 warnings.
Same with `show warnings` in query.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by setting the global value `max_error_count` on the db to a higher value (max value `65535`).

See more in [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_error_count)